# In-text citation: list all authors for pieces with three (or fewer) authors?

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib

I'm preparing a manuscript for submission to a journal that uses a citation format similar to `natbib`'s `authoryear`, but that requires full author lists for in-text citations when there are three authors, as well as when there are two authors.

Is there a package or command that will do this automatically for me?  The commands `\citet*` and `\citep*` from `natbib` are great, but they don't automatically identify cases where there are three or fewer authors.  Furthermore it gets really tricky when I'm parenthetically citing multiple sources (in the same citation), some of which have three authors, and some of which have more authors.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It would be helpful if you indicated which bibliography style (.bst) file you are using. The reason this would be helpful is because the `natbib` manual states that the "starred [citation command] versions can only list the full authors if the .bst file supports this feature; otherwise, the abbreviated list is printed."

Comment: I'm using bes.bst.  The BES here stands for British Ecological Society.

But I'm pretty sure that this isn't really relevant.  I'm not trying to use the starred citation format.  The starred citation format works *fine* with this version of bst, but does not do what I want.

What I want is something that will *automatically* identify citations with three authors, and expand those without messing with longer citation lists.

Comment: Good news: "bes.bst" lends itself perfectly to the method I describe in my answer, viz., replacing the existing function "format.lab.names". The method works both with the ordinary and the starred versions of the `\citet` and `\citep` commands. The `\citet` and `\citep` commands will list all authors *if there are fewer than four* of them, and they'll generate a "FirstAuthor et al" citation in all other cases.

Answer (score 6):

Since you're submitting a paper to a journal that has certain formatting requirements for the paper's bibliography (and lots of other aspects of the paper too, no doubt!), you should ask (if you haven't already done so) for a BibTeX bibliography style (.bst) file that implements the journal's requirements. With any luck, this .bst file will be compatible with `natbib` *and* also implement the journal's house style (of making you cite the names of all authors of pieces that have three or fewer authors).

If you're not that lucky, there are three possibilities. First, if the .bst file is *not* compatible with `natbib`, you're obviously out of luck. (Fortunately, though, `natbib` is enormously robust and works with the overwhelming majority of .bst files.) Second, if the .bst file *is* compatible with `natbib` but does not contain a function called `format.lab.names`, you're also out of luck. That's what's meant, basically, by the statement in natbib's manual that "starred [citation command] versions can only list the full authors if the .bst file supports this feature." (Of course, such a .bst file must also provide a few functions that call the `format.lab.names` function...)

Third, if the .bst file *does* contain such a function but doesn't implement the journal's house style, i.e., if the `\cite[pt]*` macros output `Adams et~al.` for a piece that has exactly three authors (and the first author's surname is "Adams"...), you are *not* out of luck. All you need to do is to replace the existing `format.lab.names` function with one that does obey the journal's house style. The existing `format.lab.names` function should (more or less...) look like:

```
FUNCTION {format.lab.names}
{ 's :=
  "" 't :=
  s #1 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
  s num.names$ duplicate$
  #2 >
    { pop$
      " " * bbl.etal *
    }
    { #2 <
        'skip$
        { s #2 "{ff }{vv }{ll}{ jj}" format.name$ "others" =
            {
              " " * bbl.etal *
            }
            { bbl.and space.word * s #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
              * }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

You should replace this code with the following code:

```
FUNCTION {format.lab.names}
{'s :=
 "" 't :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
      't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          nameptr #2 =
          numnames #3 > and
            { "others" 't :=
              #1 'namesleft := }
            'skip$
          if$
          namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            {
              s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
                { 't := }
                { pop$ }
              if$
                  t "others" =
                {
                  " " * bbl.etal *
                }
                {
                  numnames #2 >
                    { "," * }
                    'skip$
                  if$
                  bbl.and
                  space.word * t *
                }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}
```

After making this replacement, save the .bst file under a new name and adjust the `\bibliographystyle` command to point to the new file.

If you get complaints from BibTeX about nonexistent `bbl.and` and/or `bbl.etal` functions, just add the following code to the new .bst file (somewhere near the top of the file, soon after the start of the section in which the bibtex functions are defined):

```
FUNCTION {bbl.and}
{ "and"}
FUNCTION {bbl.etal}
{ "et~al." }
```

Comment: Okay, great!<br>

I only had to make minor changes to your suggested replacement.  In particular, the in-text citations use \& instead of bbl.and, and in order to not put a comma before the ampersand I changed the number of names after which to put a comma:<br>

<code>
numnames #3 >
                    { "," * }
                    'skip$
                  if$
                  " \& "
                  space.word * t *
</code>

Comment: In short, you found out how to get from "Eats, Shoots, and Leaves" to "Eats, Shoots & Leaves". :-) Congrats!