# How to Include Oxford Comma when Using \citet*

Tags: citing, natbib, punctuation

I am using the `aer` bibliography style with BibTeX. I am wanting to write out citations in the text with three or more coauthors. An easy way to do this is to use `\citet*`, `\citep*`, etc. as opposed to `\citet`, `\citep`, etc. However, there is no Oxford comma. How can I get it to include a comma before the `and`?

Note that this has been asked, but not answered, in a comment by @user67403 (the last comment on the question) here: [Revise the AER bibliography style to write out all names if a piece has three authors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215403/revise-the-aer-bibliography-style-to-write-out-all-names-if-a-piece-has-three-au)

Comment: I'm confused. The answer there shows how to modify the full names output of the.bst file to get the Oxford comma. Have you tried that modification? If so, and it doesn't work, post a minimal example that shows the problem. But I think your question is simply an exact duplicate.

Comment: I initially didn't want to deal with modifying the .bst file and wanted another solution. But I tried changing the .bst file as described in the other answer, and it worked well.