# How to list more than two authors in a citation

Tags: bibtex, natbib, apa-style

When I cite a paper with more than 2 authors, the citation in the text body is "Author1 et al.". Is it possible to change this default number from 2 to 3, so that a paper with 3 authors will be cited as "Author1 and Author2 and Author3"?

I work with bibtex and natbib. I looked at the [natbib reference](https://gking.harvard.edu/files/natnotes2.pdf) but did not find this option.

Comment: Could you consider using `biblatex`? It's just a matter of changing the values of the keys `maxcitenames` and `mincitenames`.

Comment: it is determined by the bibtex style you are using, most will cut off at a higher number.

Comment: The question is tagged apa. This is how APA wants it.

Comment: Which bibliography style do you employ? The solution to your query involves modifying the bibliography style. Incidentally, for publications with exactly three authors, do you really want a citation call-out of the form "Author1 and Author2 and Author3", or would you prefer either "Author1, Author2 and Author3" or "Author1, Author2, and Author3"? (The latter possibility uses the "Oxford" comma...) Finally, should the citation call-out revert to "Author1 et al." for publications with four or more authors? If not, where's your preferred cut-off? Please advise.

Comment: By the way, might the postings [In-text citation: list all authors for pieces with three (or fewer) authors?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38413/5001) and [Citation “et al.” only for four and more authors with natbib and jf.bst](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196750/5001) be of use to you?

Comment: @Mico I read these two postings, which recommend to change the function format.lab.names. I did this change in apa.bst. But, I got an error message for each reference: "You can't pop an empty literal stack for entry"...

Comment: @Bernard I switched to biblatex using the command "\usepackage[citestyle=apa,mincitenames=1,maxcitenames=3,bibstyle=authoryear]{biblatex}". But now, I see all the authors even in references with 5 authors...

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi - Thanks for letting me know which bibliography style you employ. I'll post an answer shortly.

Comment: @Erel Segal-Halevi: If you don't want to see all authors in references, use `minnames=1, maxnames=3`, to have the same parameters in references and citations. You also can use `minbibnames =`, `maxbibnames=` to have different parameters.

Comment: @Bernard I try \usepackage[citestyle=apa,mincitenames=1,maxcitenames=3,minbibnames=1,maxbibnames=3,minnames=1,maxnames=3,bibstyle=authoryear]{biblatex}   and  \usepackage[citestyle=apa,minnames=1,maxnames=3,bibstyle=authoryear]{biblatex}  and still get 5 author names... I use Biber 2.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've indicated that you use the `apa` bibliography style. I suggest you proceed as follows to achieve your formatting objective:

- Find the file `apa.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file and call the copy, say, `apa-erel.bst`.
- Open the file `apa-erel.bst` in a text editor. (The editor you use for the main tex file will do fine.
- In the file `apa-erel.bst`, locate the function `format.lab.names`. (In my copy of this file, the function starts on line 866.)
- Delete (or comment out) all 17 or so lines of this function and replace them with the following code:

  ```
  FUNCTION {bbl.and}
  { "and"}
  FUNCTION {space.word}
  { " " swap$ * " " * }
  FUNCTION {format.lab.names}
  {'s :=
   "" 't :=
    #1 'nameptr :=
    s num.names$ 'numnames :=
    numnames 'namesleft :=
      { namesleft #0 > }
      { s nameptr
        "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
        't :=
        nameptr #1 >
          {
            nameptr #2 =
            numnames #3 > and
              { "others" 't :=
                #1 'namesleft := }
              'skip$
            if$
            namesleft #1 >
              { ", " * t * }
              {
                s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
                  { 't := }
                  { pop$ }
                if$
                t "others" =
                  { " et~al." * }
                  {
                    numnames #2 >
                      { "," * }
                      'skip$
                    if$
                    bbl.and
                    space.word * t *
                  }
                if$
              }
            if$
          }
          't
        if$
        nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
        namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
      }
    while$
  }
  ```
- Save the file `apa-erel.bst`, either in a directory that's searched by BibTeX or in the directory where your main tex file is located. If you choose the former method, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution suitably.
- In your main tex file, change the instruction `\bibliographystyle{apa}` to `\bibliographystyle{apa-erel}` and perform a full recompile cycle -- latex, bibtex, latex, latex -- to fully propagate all changes.

Happy BibTeXing!

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{ab, author = "A and B", title = "X", year = 3001, }
@misc{abc, author = "A and B and C", title = "Y", year = 3002, }
@misc{abcd, author = "A and B and C and D", title = "Z", year = 3003, }

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apa-erel}
\begin{document}
\cite{ab}

\cite{abc}

\cite{abcd}

\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! So the solution is different for each bst file?

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi - I'd say the solution is (more or less) the same for all bst files created with the `makebst` utility. (`makebst` was written by the author of the `natbib` package.) Lots and lots of bst files fall into this category. For other styles, including `apa`, the solution has to be bespoke. Some really old bib styles (especially those that generate only numeric-style citation call-outs)  don't even feature a function called `format.lab.names`. In such cases, it's pretty much hopeless (pointless?!) to try to come up with a solution.