# Springer Nature: print up to three authors in an inline citation

Tags: bibtex, natbib, bibliographystyle, springernature

I am using the springer nature template with the `sn-mathphys-num` bibliography style (https://www.springernature.com/gp/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support/see-where-our-services-will-take-you/18782940). I need a numbered style, and I would like to use `\citet` to cite authors with corresponding numbers for inline citations.
Unfortunately, this does only print one author followed by "et al." if the reference has more than two authors. How can I change this to  print all three authors for an entry with exactly three authors?

Comment: Are you familiar with the query [In-text citation: list all authors for pieces with three (or fewer) authors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38413/5001)?

Comment: @Mico Yes, I tried your comment there. Now, after trying it again, I am left with the error "space.word is an unknown function". Do you know what I have to insert to fix that? Sorry, I am not at all familiar with writing this type of TeX code.

Comment: @Mico I fixed the problem with space.word. Unfortunately, it still does not print three authors. There were originally two functions, which were called by the function format.lab.names: alpha.format.lab.names and standard.format.lab.names. I deleted all three functions and inserted the code from the other query. Could this be the problem?